# How do I format JDateChooser into dd-mm-yyyy?

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat, jdatechooser

I am trying to output the current date format into:

`DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`, but it is outputting like this:

`Fri Dec 02 14:03:59 AEST 2016`

Here is my code:

```
JDateChooser datePurchased = new JDateChooser();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
Date newDate = new Date();
datePurchased.setDate(newDate);
```

I am now printing the result like this:

```
System.out.println(newDate.toString());
```

But this does not print out what I want, as per above.

My goal output is: `02/12/2016`, how do I go about doing this, I've tried looking around but I cannot find the likes to solve my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: where are you using the `dateFormat` object?

Comment: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is simple enough, a `Date` is a representation in epoch time and doesn't have a modifiable format. Instead, you format it when you want to display it (or otherwise obtain a **`String`** *representation*). Additionally, you need `M` for *months* (`m` is *minutes*) and if you want `/` use that instead of `-`. For example,

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date newDate = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(newDate));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the date but no using the formatter, you need to do:

```
String pattern  = "dd-MM-yyyy";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
System.out.println(formatter.format(newDate));
```

## edit:

if your goal output is: **02/12/2016**
then in the pattern in the format incorrect, you will need to use slash and not hyphens

use instead **dd/mm/yyyy**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code:

```
  bill_date.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

In here `bill_date` is instance of the `JDateChooser`.